# In android, how to get the image from json?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, arrays

In android,  how to insert image into sqlite database  and how to get the image from json result?anyone help me out with this..I'm new to android.... i have posted my json response below...

```
{
        "response": {
            "success": "1",            
            "product_image": [
                "ZG93bmxvYWQuanBn",
                "W0JANDI2NjhlYjA=",
                "W0JANDI2NTdkZDA=",
                "W0JANDI2NmNhNzA=",
                "W0JANDI2NzAyNzA=",
                "W0JANDI2NzNiYTA=",
                "W0JANDI2NzY4ODg=",
                "W0JANDI2N2EzNzg=",
                "W0JANDI2N2NkMzA=",
                "W0JANDI2ODAzMjA=",
                "W0JANDI2ODJmODg=",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "W0JANDI2NjhlYjA=",
                "W0JANDI2NTdkZDA=",
                "W0JANDI2NmNhNzA=",
                "W0JANDI2NzAyNzA=",
                "W0JANDI2NzNiYTA=",
                "W0JANDI2NzY4ODg=",
                "W0JANDI2N2EzNzg=",
                "W0JANDI2N2NkMzA=",
                "W0JANDI2ODAzMjA=",
                "W0JANDI2ODJmODg=",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                "bnVsbA==",
                           ]
}
}
```

Image is encoded like below in web service...

$product_image[]=based64_code($row['productimage']));

Comment: can you show your json sample

Comment: What have you done so far? Please post some code.

Comment: Where is this image stored? Do you have it on your SD card? If yes, you could have the address on your JSON and load the bitmap on your application based on this address. **Please provide more details, show your JSON sample**.

Comment: @BenitoBertoli  Ok,I will.....

Comment: @rogcg yes sqlite Db get stored in SD card....

Comment: Refer this [android-how-to-parse-json-and-show](http://developer-android-tutorial.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-how-to-parse-json-and-show.html)

Comment: @user2427819 I have posted my json sample.. look at my question....

Comment: post your code and we will help, from your json itself is not properly closed. JSON is incomplete

Comment: @Brendon I have posted a part of the Json response, it is to lengthy.....

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is to encode your image as `Base64` string and put it into a field of your JSON object on sending side, and decode it on receiving side, like

```
[ "image":"aslfdkjlsjkfdlsjdfkjshk===" ]
```

It's a pretty standard way for such sort of things

UPDATE:
for encoding/decoding `byte[] <-> String` you can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html

Comment: I have got this format please see my post above but I tried many ways to insert images in sqlite database but I couldn't....

Comment: the things in your post `"product_image": [ "ZG93bmxvYWQuanBn", "W0JANDI2NjhlYjA=",..]` are not a valid `Base64` string. Instead you have an array of some strings here... Or are you trying to send several images here? please clearify.

Comment: Image is encoded like below in web service...

$product_image[]=based64_code($row['productimage']));